# Combining statistic queries from the same table

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have seen recently on SO a request to combine three queries from the same `history` table into one to improve performances.

The three queries were

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history;
SELECT COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history 
    WHERE date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -30 DAY));
SELECT COUNT(*) as number, SUM(order_total) as sum FROM history
    WHERE date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());
```

So I thought I'd format a more general question, with the above as example case: how can more queries be combined, and how best to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries all access the same variables and only differ in the conditions used to run the sum and the totals.

To run this all in a single query we'll have to assign each result to a different column, so instead of `number` and `sum` we'll have `number1`, `number2`, ... `sum3`, in order to access the results.

## Basic replacement

In general, `COUNT()`, `SUM()` etc. are [aggregate functions](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx), so we are going to replace each instance with a new expression which incorporates the condition.

For example: `COUNT(*) WHERE some_condition` is the same as

```
add 1 for each record among the records where <some_condition>
```

which can rewritten (albeit a little slower) as

```
add 1 if <some_condition>, else 0, for each record among ALL the records
```

which is

```
SUM(IF(<some_condition>, 1, 0))
```

The same applies for `SUM(value) WHERE <some_condition>`: it becomes `SUM(IF(<some_condition>, value, 0))`.

When considering `MIN()`, `MAX()` and `AVG()`, we see that the default value of 0 can be problematic. This issue is solved by using NULL instead of 0.

Our first iteration allows for simple substitutions:

```
Single query                 Combined query
COUNT(*)                     SUM(<conditionalOne>)
SUM(value)                   SUM(<conditionalValue>)
AVG(value)                   AVG(<conditionalValue>)
MIN(value)                   MIN(<conditionalValue>)
...
```

where `<conditionalValue>` is, if `<condition>` is present,

```
IF(<condition>, value, NULL)
```

and otherwise simply `value`. `<conditionalOne>` is a `<conditionalValue>` where value is equal to 1. Otherwise, `value` can be a field name or an expression.

So our example queries become:

```
SELECT
    SUM(1) AS number1, SUM(order_total) AS sum1,
    SUM(IF(date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)), 1, NULL)) AS number2,
    SUM(IF(date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -30 DAY)), order_total, NULL)) AS sum2,
    SUM(IF(date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()), 1, NULL)) AS number3,
    SUM(IF(date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()), order_total, NULL)) AS sum3
FROM history;
```

## Merging the WHEREs

In this case there is at least one condition which is valid for the whole table, i.e. one query has no `WHERE`; so we need to scan the whole table. We might then just as well do without the `WHERE` altogether.

Otherwise we would merge the three conditions and use the largest or most permissive of them (so if we were selecting last year, last month and last week, we would actually add only the select for last year).

We can do this automatically and hope in the MySQL optimizer to figure things out:

```
WHERE (<condition1>) OR (<condition2>) OR (<condition3>);
```

## Index optimization

Due to indexing, it may well be the case that the single query will actually run *slower* than several disjointed queries. This will often happen if the conditions and the values actually target several different columns, making indexing less efficient.

If there are no indexes in place at all, then merging the queries ought to always be more convenient than running them separately.

In theory we would like to have a [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) containing all columns appearing in the `WHERE` clause, from those with minimum cardinality to those with maximum cardinality, followed by all the columns appearing in the expressions. This way the MySQL selector will quickly zero on the desired rows, and will also find the required values already present in memory.

In this example the conditions are based on `date` and the query asks for `order_total`, so we would create the index with just the two columns.

```
 CREATE INDEX history_stat_ndx ON history(`date`, order_total);
```

In practice, though, it may well be the case that the covering index is just too large to be accepted, or if it is, to be beneficial. In that case we would still merge several queries, but this time into more than one query:

- a query requiring a full table scan and/or a lot of columns, especially if the other queries do not need the same, would go by itself, and would be merged with all other queries with the same characteristics, and **not be indexed** (we would gain little from indexing. Not for the WHERE since there is a full table scan, not from coverage since there're too many columns).
- all queries requiring similar conditions or similar sets of columns in the expressions could be grouped together, and possibly indexed if the conditions really are similar. Each group might have a different index of its own, optimized for that group and its expressions.